# Google Visualization Barformat Options

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm working on Google's Table Chart Recently.
Now I have some issues on setting the BarFormat.
I'm able to set min and max value for the bar range, 
but it's only for the whole table.
Is there any way to set the range separately?
And the another question is what are the 'v' and 'f' stands for in the second column?
Below is the example.

```
  function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
    data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
    data.addColumn('number', 'QQ');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true,10000],
      ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false,8000],
      ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true,12500],
      ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true,7000]
    ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    var formatter = new google.visualization.BarFormat({width: 100,colorPositive:'red',colorNegative:'blue',max:20000,min:0});
    formatter.format(data, 3); // Apply formatter to second column
    table.draw(data, {allowHtml: true,showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '50%'});
  }
```

Thanks for helping~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**

you can use literal values to populate cells in google's data table (`'Mike'`, `10000`, etc...)

or use their *object notation*, where...
`v:` = value
`f:` = formatted value

which align with data table methods...

`getValue(row, col)` and `setValue(row, col, val)`
`getFormattedValue(row, col)` and `setFormattedValue(row, col, formatVal)`
`setCell(row, col, val, formatVal)`

**2)**

as noted, the `format` method applies the format to the entire table

to format using a different `min` and `max` for each row,

you could create a new data table for each row,

format the new data table,

then add all the formatted rows to another final data table

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawTable,
  packages:['table']
});

function drawTable() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
  data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
  data.addColumn('number', 'QQ');

  // data table used to join rows back together
  var joinData = data.clone();

  data.addColumn('number', 'min');
  data.addColumn('number', 'max');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true, 10000, 0, 20000],
    ['Jim',   {v: 8000,  f: '$8,000'}, false, 8000, 0, 16000],
    ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true, 12500, 0, 25000],
    ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'}, true, 7000, 0, 14000]
  ]);

  var rowData = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < data.getNumberOfRows(); r++) {
    // create view for each data row
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setRows([r]);
    var viewData = view.toDataTable();

    // format new data table
    var formatter = new google.visualization.BarFormat({
      width: 100,
      colorPositive: 'red',
      colorNegative: 'blue',
      max: data.getValue(r, 5),
      min: data.getValue(r, 4)
    });
    formatter.format(viewData, 3);

    // add values to join table
    var row = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < joinData.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
      row.push({
        v: viewData.getValue(0, c),
        f: viewData.getFormattedValue(0, c)
      });
    }
    joinData.addRow(row);
  }

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
  table.draw(joinData, {
    allowHtml: true,
    showRowNumber: true,
    width: '100%',
    height: '50%'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for helping, but I still can't figure out how to set the min and max range of the bar for each row.
ex.
Mike: min 0, max 20000
Jim: min 0, max 16000
Alice: min 0, max 25000
Bob: min 0, max 14000